# creating mutilple databases inside postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker

My Application needs 3 databases. I am using PostgreSQL.
How can I launch all the 3 databases in single container at one shot. All 3 have different tables & scripts. For each of those, `*.sql` files are being executed by copying in the `Dockerfile`.

I tried in conventional way . Didn't work.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 

ENV POSTGRES_DB my_db_dev
COPY /devdb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


ENV POSTGRES_DB my_db_test
COPY /testdb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


ENV POSTGRES_DB my_db_prod
COPY /proddb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Here, only the last DB (my_db_prod) is launching up.

How Can I make all 3 up at once ?

Comment: When you rewrite POSTGRES_DB env the postgresql not started, so the only last db created, you can access container and login psql to create other databases;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ENV` Dockerfile command sets an environment variable at build-time.
The `COPY` is also executed at build-time, basically overwriting the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

When you invoke these actions, the latest executed overrides the previous one, thus the image final state will have `POSTGRES_DB=my_db_prod` and the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will have the contents of `proddb.sql`.

The database is not created at build-time. Instead, it is created at run-time, following the instructions from `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ (/proddb.sql )` and `POSTGRES_DB my_db_prod`, hence this is the state in which the succession of commands from build-time left the image.

To create multiple databases, you can merge the scripts of the 3 entrypoints in a single one, or even better, have one script for each DB and have the scripts read different ENVs:

```
COPY ./create_second_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_second_db.sql
COPY ./create_third_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_third_db.sql
```

[Here](https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases) is a complete example that can save some time.

Comment: In that case My Dockerfile shud only contain the below thing?

Comment: FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres COPY ./create_first_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_second_db.sqlCOPY ./create_second_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_second_db.sql
COPY ./create_third_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_third_db.sql

Comment: Shud I add CREATE DATABASE query in script itself?

Comment: Having the DBs created in the big `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will work, but it is cleaner to have init scripts under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. Those should be discovered by the initdb and executed.

Comment: @Ranjith , [here](https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases) is an example that might save you some time. However, with Docker you have a very small overhead if you run 3 different containers, one for each database. Actually, this is a better practice, hence it will better isolate your dev/test/prod scopes. Imagine you'd need to run a stress test on your test environment DB - this will affect the dev and prod databases as well, hence they're running in the same container.

Comment: Thanks Neo. That example did indeed helps. Regarding 3 databases,  I only named them that way here ( dev/test/prod) . They are not actually dev-prod-test. But my application really needs 3 different databases ( system, config, users) . In this scenario, having one container for all 3 db's makes sense?....Please advise.. I am a newbie here

Comment: It makes perfect sense to have those 3 DBs in the same container. Falling in the other extreme, where you create one container for every minor service in your stack may lead you to the spaghetti-code/mesh anti-pattern. An extreme example: you don't want to create a micro-service that returns the sum of two numbers instead of calculating the sum in the main service. Back to the databases: if one day you'll need to distribute those 3 DBs across multiple containers/nodes, due to performance issues, you might address the problem when it will arise. _Early optimization is the root of all evil_

Answer (score 0):

i follow up this way and it working for me.

my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'

  db:
    image: postgres:10.5
    container_name: pg
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - /initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

i mount one folder **initdb** from docker host to inside postgres container like above.
inside initdb have 2 sql files. and it successful ran for both script sql.

Comment: How about the ownership of each databases? where do we specify/assign that?

Comment: Dear Ranjith, i special this in side sql script.